# An operator inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory

I would be most thankful if you could help me prove the following operator inequality. Let $A$ be an arbitrary linear operator on a Hilbert space, satisfying
$$\left\|AA^{\ast} - A^{\ast}A\right\|\leq 2a$$
where $A^{\ast}$ is the Hermitian adjoint and $a>0$ is a constant. Let $\varepsilon$ be equal to either $+1$ or $-1$. Then show that 
$$2\sqrt{A^{\ast}A + aI} - \varepsilon\left(A + A^{\ast}\right) \geq 0$$ 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this answer we assume that $A$ is a [bounded operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) on a complex Hilbert space $H$.

Sketched proof and hints:

1. We may uniquely write $A=B+iC$, where $B$ and $C$ are selfadjoint operators. Define selfadjoint operator $D:=i[C,B]=D^{\dagger}$. Then OP's statement reads
   $$\tag{1} ||D|| ~\leq ~a  \qquad \Rightarrow  \qquad \sqrt{A^{\dagger}A+aI} ~\geq~ \pm B. $$
2. Show that (1) is a consequence of 
   $$ \tag{2}||D|| ~\leq ~a  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad\sqrt{A^{\dagger}A+aI}~\geq~ \sqrt{ B^2  }. $$
3. Show that (2) is a consequence of 
   $$ \tag{3}||D|| ~\leq ~a  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad\sqrt{A^{\dagger}A+aI}~\geq~ \sqrt{ B^2 +C^2 }. $$
4. Show that (3) is equivalent to 
   $$ \tag{4}||D|| ~\leq ~a  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad A^{\dagger}A+aI~\geq~  B^2 +C^2 . $$
5. Show that (4) is equivalent to 
   $$\tag{5}||D|| ~\leq ~a  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad aI~\geq~  D .$$
6. Show (5).